# sql query not returning the correct MTD cumulative sum

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following table "card_txns":

```
user_sign_month      month      months_since_cust      country      txn_amt
2018-01              2018-01        1                      DE           100
2018-01              2018-02        1                      DE           100
2018-01              2018-03        1                      DE           100
2019-01              2019-01        1                      IN           100
2019-02              2019-02        1                      US           1,000
2019-03              2019-03        1                      DE           1,000
2019-04              2019-04        1                      US           1,000
```

I want to see the cumulative sum, total sum by txn_month column for 2019, and the following query is not returning that

```
SELECT month AS Tx_MONTH,
       SUM(txn_amt) AS Total_transactions_2019,
       (SELECT SUM(txn_amt)
          FROM card_txns AS b
         WHERE a.month >= b.month
           AND a.country = b.country) AS CUM_MTD_Total
  FROM card_txns AS a AND substring(month, 1, 4) = '2019'
 GROUP BY month
 ORDER BY month
```

The output should look like this:

```
Tx_MONTH   Total_transactions_2019  CUM_MTD_Total
2019-01    100                      100
2019-02    100                      1100
2019-03    100                      2100
2019-04    100                      3100
```

I want to have the cumulative sum by month sorted in the above manner, s o 2019-01 should appear first and so on.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: you can check out the answer again. This is the [demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=06aeb7b7d73d721b2ada296b9b36b0f0)

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan: your demonstration looks fine but my txn_amt column is a string and if I apply the query as mentioned below, it only sums up to the number where there is no , sperator. So, for instance, it is dropping 1,000 from the sum. Any ideas qhy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use window functions:

```
SELECT month AS Tx_MONTH, SUM(txn_amt) as Total_transactions_2019,
       SUM(txn_amt) OVER (ORDER BY month) as MTD_Total
FROM card_txns ct
WHERE month LIKE '2019-%'
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=cefef258027f96ccb881d0c7c29da2b0) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I am getting an error while using this query :SQL Error: Syntax error: Encountered " "(" "( "" at line 2, column 52.
Was expecting:
    <EOF>

Comment: This is SQL standard syntax and nowadays pretty much all databases support window functions.

Comment: I have updated my question. Would you mind looking into it again?

Comment: @Django0602 . . . This works fine in SQLite.  I added a db<>fiddle.

Comment: But again, in your fiddle you are using the input as 1000 but my input is 1,000 as my txn_amt column is a string, and the moment you change that you will not see any output from your fiddle. How should I treat the , separator in my txn_amt column?

Comment: @Django0602 . . . Numbers should be stored as numbers, not strings.  Fix your data.  Or get rid of the comma so the value can be used as a number.